# How to change a rectangle in processing into a image for a game that I am making?

Tags: java, processing

Here is my code for what is used in the spaceship class:

```
class SpaceShip extends GameObject
        {
          //contructor for the player's spaceship
          SpaceShip()
          {
             x = width/2;
             y = height/2;
             dx = 0;
             dy = 0;
          }

          void show()
          {
            fill(193, 152 , 240);
            //This is what is needed to be changed into an image whilst keeping this as a sort of hitbox per-say
            rect(x, y, 50, 50);
          }
          void act()
            {
            dx = 0;
            dy = 0;

            if(upkey) dy = -5;
            if(leftkey) dx = -5;
            if(rightkey) dx = 5;
            if(downkey) dy = 5;
            //if(spacekey)//fire 

              x = x + dx;
              y = y + dy;
            }

             boolean hasDied()
             {
               return false;
             }
            }
```

If you guys could assist me with either the code or the way that this was posted (I haven't really used a site like this) then by all mean to tell me and I will try my best to respond to you guys and update this post.

Edit1: The GameObject is just some minor code which is all said in this class which is my manual code it is used to be overwritten and that is all - the classes used are: show(), act, and hasDied, each of these classes in the GameObject are all empty with some exceptions. If you would like to know further, comment and I will try my best to answer it.

Edit2: Here is what my end goal for this question is:
To make the rectangle be transparent and have the image(for this example a spaceship) shown whilst also keeping the rectangle function to be used as a hitbox for taking damage and what not. (Hope this helped clear any misconceptions of what I was trying to achieve).

Edit3: Thanks mate, here is where I am at now and what
the current code is:

```
PImage img;

class SpaceShip extends GameObject
{
  //contructor for the player's spaceship
  SpaceShip()
  {
     img = loadImage("SpaceShipSprite1.png");
     x = width/2;
     y = height/2;
     dx = 0;
     dy = 0;
  }

  void show()
  {
    fill(LightPurple_SpaceShip);
    //This is what is needed to be changed into an image whilst keeping this as a sort of hitbox per-sa
    rect(x, y, 50, 50);
    image(img, x, y, 50, 50);

  }
  void act()
  {
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;

    if(upkey) dy =-5;
    if(leftkey) dx =-5;
    if(rightkey) dx =+5;
    if(downkey) dy =+5;
    if(firekey) engine.add(new Bullet());

    x = x + dx;
    y = y + dy;
  }

  boolean hasDied()
  {
    return false;
  }

}
```

The snip of the game:
[The Game and where the character is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYS8c.png)

Edit 4 (Final Edit): Here is the final finished version for all who want to do something similar thank you to all who helped me with this dilemma and looking forward to asking more questions in the future.

```
PImage img;

class SpaceShip extends GameObject
{
  //contructor for the player's spaceship
  SpaceShip()
  {
     img = loadImage("SpaceShipSprite1.png");
     x = width/2;
     y = height/2;
     dx = 0;
     dy = 0;
  }

  void show()
  {
    noStroke();
    noFill();
    //This is what is needed to be changed into an image whilst keeping this as a sort of hitbox per-sa
    rect(x, y, 50, 50);
    image(img, x - 24.8, y, 50, 50);
  }
  void act()
  {
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;

    if(upkey) dy =-5;
    if(leftkey) dx =-5;
    if(rightkey) dx =+5;
    if(downkey) dy =+5;
    if(firekey) engine.add(new Bullet());

    x = x + dx;
    y = y + dy;
  }

  boolean hasDied()
  {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. First of all, I suggest you read about [how to ask a good question][https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] and secondly I don't know what is the `GameObject` and how it works? Is it an external library or just your manual code? If you implemented that by yourself, you need to put the code in your question.

Comment: Thank you, Hamid for the reply, there are two things I would like to say: 1. The link doesn't work so I am unable to access it but I will look it up and 2. The GameObject is just some minor code which is all said in this class which is my manual code it is used to be overwritten and that is all - the classes used are: show(), act, and hasDied, each of these classes in the GameObject are all empty with some exceptions.

Comment: If you're just starting the project you may want to consider using the open source and free https://godotengine.org/ instead.  It is capable of a lot of advanced game creation techniques but is also quite easy to learn.

Comment: John Forbes, I really am thankful for the suggestion of the engine you have supplied to me but I would rather be taught how to do these kinds of things so that I may use similar techniques further down the line, thank you for the reply though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loadImage` and `image` functions as described in the [documentation](https://processing.org/reference/image_.html):

```
PImage img;

SpaceShip() {
  // Images must be in the "data" directory to load correctly
  img = loadImage("spaceship.jpg");
  ...
}

void show() {
  image(img, x, y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot mate really helped, but there is one thing that is bothering me is that when I entered the code from what you supplied me it ended at the bottom right of the rectangle and not in the middle of the rectangle where it should be. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You need to calculate the correct position of the image. It depends on what x and y exactly mean in your program, size of the image etc. The parameters passed to `image` specify location of the upper left corner. Adjust them based on what x and y really mean.